# Cisco IE4000 Blinking Amber Lights

Tags: cisco

I have an IE4000 Cisco Switch running my small air gapped network. I came in this morning and found that ALL the ports other than the Trunk port are blinking Amber. I checked the config and the interfaces and found that the ports are up and the link is up but I get no connection on any of my computers. Normally all the ports are green because all the computers are a 1G connection. I tried to reload the switch and watching it load it showed all the ports up. These are all Ethernet ports and I haven't made any changes to the configuration in the past 4 months. Only thing I can think of that the switch rebooted when the power went out. I don't believe this is a duplex error as all the ports haven't been changed and they have been working for months.

Now if this was a port security issue the ports would be solid amber and the port would show as "shutdown". I have checked the manual for the switch and there is no LED information for flashing amber. What else should I check to get all the ports back to normal and get my connections back?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: @Zac67 Switches were logging to a server but it is not communicating to that server as it is plugged into the switch and has the flashing amber light.

Comment: I think you'll need to check the console to get more information.  The most likely scenario is you'll need to replace the switch.  "Why" is probably a curiosity at this point.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with some other network engineers they suggested I reenter the VLAN information. When doing a `show vlan x` command it said the vlans did not show up. Which is strange because I not only configured them, I named them and assigned them to specific ports. I am still unsure how the vlan database disappeared. We did have a power failure due to a storm here but even with the config and the vlan.dat file saved to flash that would not have removed the vlan.dat configuration and not the startup-configurations. Strange.

Comment: Be sure to accept your answer, so it doesn't keep popping up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

[Blinking amber](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/cisco_ie4000/hardware/installation/guide/ie4000_hig/HIGOVERV.html#96337) on the ports means **PoE is off due to a fault.**  Perhaps the switch's power supply is malfunctioning and no longer able to provide PoE.

I'd take Zac67's advice and check the logs.  However, it's a good guess the switch will need to be replaced.

Comment: That's only for the dedicated PoE status LED. The port status LEDs have no documented blinking amber mode. (err-disable???)

Comment: @Ricky err-disable would be solid amber. We are not using PoE so I am pretty sure it is not that.